# Передать данные из представления в контроллер JsonResult

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

Имеется представление следующего типа, которое нужно переделать под json:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("ViewM", "ModelC") }))
{
    <input type="text" name="str" />
    <input type="text" name="str2" />
     <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Отобразить результат" />
}
```

И контроллер ModelC. В нём метод ViewM с возвращаемым значением типа Json

```
public JsonResult ViewM()
{
    var result = new List<P>();
    result.Add(new P { Name = "N1", Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P{ Name = "N2", Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P{ Name = "N3", Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P { Name = "N4", Value = 4 });
    return Json(new { Countries = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ну и класс со свойствами

```
 public class P
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Если бы  ViewM был бы типа ActionResult, то в любое поле было было бы легко передать значение Name. Это бы выглядело примерно так:

```
public ActionResult ViewM(string str, string str2)
{
    var result = new List<P>();
    result.Add(new P { Name = str, Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P{ Name = str2, Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P{ Name = "N3", Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P { Name = "N4", Value = 4 });
    return PartialView(result)
}
```

Но проблема в том, что таким же образом нельзя сделать с JsonResult.

```
public JsonResult ViewM(string str, string str2)
{
    var result = new List<P>();
    result.Add(new P { Name = str, Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P{ Name = str2, Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P{ Name = "N3", Value = 6 });
    result.Add(new P { Name = "N4", Value = 4 });
    return Json(new { Countries = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Потому как из Ajax.BeginForm не передаются значения... Как мне поправить Ajax.BeginForm, чтобы значения успешно передались для Json?

Answer (score 1):

У метода Ajax.BeginForm есть перегруженная версия, одним из параметров которой является object routeValues или RouteValueDictionary routeValues. Так вот, этим параметром вы можете передать входящие в метод действия значения в виде (для object):

```
 new {str = "first parameter value", str2 = "second parameter value"},
```

для RouteValueDictionary:

```
 new RouteValueDictionary{{"str","first parameter value"}, {"str2","second parameter value"}}.
```

Важный момент заключается в именах входящих параметров вашего метода и именах параметров для routeValues - они должны совпадать. Поэтому я не менял их имена в вышеуказанном примере, а сделал совпадение с именами вашего метода ViewM.